# how to compute mutual information MapReduce based in R??

Tags: mapreduce, rhadoop

I want to compute mutual information for all x, y in features : I(x , y)
So I need to compute P(x) P(y) and P(x, Y) in Data for example:

> X   Y
>      -    -    yes 2    no  2    yes 2     no  1    yes 1
>
> p(yes)=3/5 p(2)=3/5 p(yes,2)=2/5

counting in Map Reduce is easy and I did it for P(x) and P(y)
but for p(x, Y) I want to compute co-occuring in each object.

I write a Map-function:

```
  mapper <- function(key, line) {

      fvec <- unlist(strsplit(line, split = " "))

      for(i in 1:55){

        for(j in (i+1):56){
               fvec<-c(fvec,paste0(fvec[i],",",fvec[j]))}}

      keyval(fvec, 1)
    }
```

"fvec" is a vector of features as first row in our example :

```
 fvec[1]="yes" "2"
```

in for loops I want to concatenate this features so that

```
fvec[1]="yes" "2" "yes2"
```

in Order to count the Occurance of yes-2 together in reduce func :

```
 reduce = function(k,v)
        {return(keyval(k,length(v)))
```

but because of "LOOP PROBLEM" in Hadoop it does not work properly.
please help me with a R solution to handle it :)